# Is it possible to set the Windows Taskbar Preview pop-ups to sort alphabetically?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Sometimes when you have many instances of a process, it can get pretty ugly to switch between windows, especially when the windows' names are weird...

[image]

So, is there a setting to sort these pop-up windows alphabetically and not chronologically?

Comment: Similar: [How can I rearrange the Windows 7 taskbar previews?](http://superuser.com/questions/155285/how-can-i-rearrange-the-windows-7-taskbar-previews)

Answer (score 1):

Not natively.

Two tools come to mind.
For multiple console windows, I find using an Expose clone like [Switcher for Vista](http://insentient.net/) is a far more efficient method.

For the taskbar, try [7 taskbar tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker-v3-0) which allows you to rearrange toolbars manually.  It won't do a alphabetical auto sort however.