# Windows 7 - Taskbar Never Combine still being combined

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7 even though I've changed the taskbar settings to "never combine" the taskbar buttons keep getting grouped together. If I open multiple Windows Explorer, multiple notepads or multiple Firefox windows (of the same profile) they *all* get forced in to groups.

I want to keep the icon on left with text label on the right but be able to drag/arrange them without the whole group moving as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) to forcibly break up groups.

[image: 7+ Taskbar Tweaker will forcibly decombine taskbar items]

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of "*combine, hide labels*" is basically "*remove the labels then stack taskbar buttons for multiple instances of the same application on top of each other*". Not "*group separate taskbar buttons belonging to the same application together (side-by-side)*".

So, in other words, *none* of the options relate to un-grouping multiple instances of the same application- and what you're seeing is expected behaviour.

It's a shame MS decided not to give users the choice- but at least 3rd party software can fill the gap if it annoys you that much.

[image]

[Arrange windows within the same application in the taskbar of Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/61913/arrange-windows-within-the-same-application-in-the-taskbar-of-windows-7)

"*No. Unfortunately, it is not possible yet. Opened instances of the same application are combined and their live thumbnails cannot be reordered.*"

Here is one possible [3rd party solution](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker).

Comment: All you needed to reply with was the last line, thanks.

Comment: @john Show a little appreciation dude, we're not here to just provide links for you.

Comment: @John: except this isn't simply a technical problem needing a technical answer. Half the problem is MS's choice of words: "Combine" is ambiguous. You are a developer and it even caught you out. My answer is aimed at the typical PC user who will likely make that same mistake. Personally, I think "stack" would have been a better description than "group" because they overlap.

Comment: Some people were editing some of my questions drastically changing the context and wasting other people's time so I was in a less than thrilled mode. I appreciate your answer and I was simply letting you know that your last line was all I really needed so you would be aware so you don't waste your own time going overkill, an intended courtesy to you. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! :) I answer questions in a way I feel will help *every* person asking the same thing, not just the OP (you, in this case). 34 people have read this since yesterday, so there is bound to be a cross-section of computer literacy here. Better to write an answer pretty much anyone can understand. I think answers *everyone* can follow rack up more points in the long run as well. If we were on Server Fault then I would assume more prior knowledge and just post the URL!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Open separate instance of the application and then open your additional file in the new instance.  You'll then have two thumbnails on your taskbar.